# any_function using the upcoming std::any

Tags: c++, c++17

We are being needlessly curtailed by the standard-supplied function containers, a lot more flexibility is possible. Try `any_function`, which can contain an arbitrary functor without having to specify it's signature.

```
namespace
{

template <typename>
struct signature
{
};

//
template <typename>
struct class_ref;

//
template <typename R, typename C, typename ...A>
struct class_ref<R (C::*)(A...)>
{
  using type = C&;
};

template <typename R, typename C, typename ...A>
struct class_ref<R (C::*)(A...) const>
{
  using type = C const&;
};

template <typename R, typename C, typename ...A>
struct class_ref<R (C::*)(A...) const volatile>
{
  using type = C const volatile&;
};

//
template <typename R, typename C, typename ...A>
struct class_ref<R (C::*)(A...) &>
{
  using type = C&;
};

template <typename R, typename C, typename ...A>
struct class_ref<R (C::*)(A...) const &>
{
  using type = C const&;
};

template <typename R, typename C, typename ...A>
struct class_ref<R (C::*)(A...) const volatile &>
{
  using type = C const volatile&;
};

//
template <typename R, typename C, typename ...A>
struct class_ref<R (C::*)(A...) &&>
{
  using type = C&&;
};

template <typename R, typename C, typename ...A>
struct class_ref<R (C::*)(A...) const &&>
{
  using type = C const&&;
};

template <typename R, typename C, typename ...A>
struct class_ref<R (C::*)(A...) const volatile &&>
{
  using type = C const volatile&&;
};

template <typename F>
using class_ref_t = typename class_ref<F>::type;

//
template <typename>
struct remove_cv_seq;

//
template <typename R, typename ...A>
struct remove_cv_seq<R(A...)>
{
  using type = R(A...);
};

template <typename R, typename ...A>
struct remove_cv_seq<R(A...) const>
{
  using type = R(A...);
};

template <typename R, typename ...A>
struct remove_cv_seq<R(A...) volatile>
{
  using type = R(A...);
};

template <typename R, typename ...A>
struct remove_cv_seq<R(A...) const volatile>
{
  using type = R(A...);
};

//
template <typename R, typename ...A>
struct remove_cv_seq<R(A...) &>
{
  using type = R(A...);
};

template <typename R, typename ...A>
struct remove_cv_seq<R(A...) const &>
{
  using type = R(A...);
};

template <typename R, typename ...A>
struct remove_cv_seq<R(A...) volatile &>
{
  using type = R(A...);
};

template <typename R, typename ...A>
struct remove_cv_seq<R(A...) const volatile &>
{
  using type = R(A...);
};

//
template <typename R, typename ...A>
struct remove_cv_seq<R(A...) &&>
{
  using type = R(A...);
};

template <typename R, typename ...A>
struct remove_cv_seq<R(A...) const &&>
{
  using type = R(A...);
};

template <typename R, typename ...A>
struct remove_cv_seq<R(A...) volatile &&>
{
  using type = R(A...);
};

template <typename R, typename ...A>
struct remove_cv_seq<R(A...) const volatile &&>
{
  using type = R(A...);
};

template <typename F>
constexpr inline auto extract_signature(F* const) noexcept
{
  return signature<typename remove_cv_seq<F>::type>();
}

template <typename C, typename F>
constexpr inline auto extract_signature(F C::* const) noexcept
{
  return signature<typename remove_cv_seq<F>::type>();
}

template <typename F>
constexpr inline auto extract_signature(F const&) noexcept ->
  decltype(&F::operator(), extract_signature(&F::operator()))
{
  return extract_signature(&F::operator());
}

}

template <typename Any = ::std::experimental::any>
class any_function
{
  using typeid_t = ::std::uintptr_t;

  #if defined(__GNUC__)
  template <typename T>
  static typeid_t type_id() noexcept
  {
    return typeid_t(type_id<T>);
  }
  #else
  template <typename T>
  static typeid_t type_id() noexcept
  {
    static char const type_id{};

    return typeid_t(&type_id);
  }
  #endif // __GNUC__

  void (*f_)(Any const&, void const*, void*);

  Any any_;

#ifndef NDEBUG
  typeid_t tuple_type_id_;
#endif // NDEBUG

  template <typename F, typename R, typename ...A, ::std::size_t ...I>
  static ::std::enable_if_t<!::std::is_void<R>{}>
  do_invoke(F const& f,
    ::std::tuple<A...> const& t,
    Any& r,
    ::std::index_sequence<I...> const) noexcept(
      noexcept(::std::invoke(f, ::std::get<I>(t)...))
    )
  {
    r = ::std::invoke(f, ::std::get<I>(t)...);
  }

  template <typename F, typename R, typename ...A, ::std::size_t ...I>
  static ::std::enable_if_t<::std::is_void<R>{}>
  do_invoke(F const& f,
    ::std::tuple<A...> const& t,
    Any&,
    ::std::index_sequence<I...> const) noexcept(
      noexcept(::std::invoke(f, ::std::get<I>(t)...))
    )
  {
    ::std::invoke(f, ::std::get<I>(t)...);
  }

  template <typename F, typename R, typename ...A>
  static ::std::enable_if_t<!::std::is_member_function_pointer<F>{}>
  invoker(Any const& any,
    void const* const v,
    void* const r) noexcept(
    noexcept(do_invoke<F, R, A...>(
      ::std::experimental::any_cast<F const&>(any),
      *static_cast<::std::tuple<A...> const*>(v),
      *static_cast<Any*>(r),
      ::std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(A)>())
    )
  )
  {
    do_invoke<F, R, A...>(
      ::std::experimental::any_cast<F const&>(any),
      *static_cast<::std::tuple<A...> const*>(v),
      *static_cast<Any*>(r),
      ::std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(A)>()
    );
  }

  template <typename F, typename R, typename ...A>
  static ::std::enable_if_t<::std::is_member_function_pointer<F>{}>
  invoker(Any const& any,
    void const* const v,
    void* const r) noexcept(
    noexcept(do_invoke<F, R, A...>(
      ::std::experimental::any_cast<F const&>(any),
      *static_cast<::std::tuple<class_ref_t<F>, A...> const*>(v),
      *static_cast<Any*>(r),
      ::std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(A) + 1>())
    )
  )
  {
    do_invoke<F, R, A...>(
      ::std::experimental::any_cast<F const&>(any),
      *static_cast<::std::tuple<class_ref_t<F>, A...> const*>(v),
      *static_cast<Any*>(r),
      ::std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(A) + 1>()
    );
  }

  template <typename F, typename R, typename ...A>
  ::std::enable_if_t<!::std::is_member_function_pointer<F>{}>
  assign(signature<R(A...)>) noexcept
  {
    f_ = invoker<F, R, A...>;

#ifndef NDEBUG
    tuple_type_id_ = type_id<::std::tuple<A...>>();
#endif // NDEBUG
  }

  template <typename F, typename R, typename ...A>
  ::std::enable_if_t<::std::is_member_function_pointer<F>{}>
  assign(signature<R(A...)>) noexcept
  {
    f_ = invoker<F, R, A...>;

#ifndef NDEBUG
    tuple_type_id_ = type_id<::std::tuple<class_ref_t<F>, A...>>();
#endif // NDEBUG
  }

public:
  template <typename T>
  struct arg_type
  {
    using type = ::std::decay_t<T>;
  };

  template <typename T>
  struct arg_type<::std::reference_wrapper<T> >
  {
    using type = T&;
  };

  template <typename T>
  using arg_type_t = typename arg_type<T>::type;

  any_function() = default;

  template <typename F,
    typename = ::std::enable_if_t<
      !::std::is_same<::std::decay_t<F>, any_function>{}
    >
  >
  any_function(F&& f) :
    any_(::std::forward<F>(f))
  {
    assign<F>(extract_signature(::std::forward<F>(f)));
  }

  any_function(any_function const&) = default;

  any_function(any_function&&) = default;

  any_function& operator=(any_function const&) = default;

  any_function& operator=(any_function&&) = default;

  template <typename F,
    typename = ::std::enable_if_t<
      !::std::is_same<::std::decay_t<F>, any_function>{}
    >
  >
  any_function& operator=(F&& f)
  {
    assign(::std::forward<F>(f));

    return *this;
  }

  explicit operator bool() const noexcept
  {
    return bool(any_);
  }

  bool empty() const noexcept
  {
    return !*this;
  }

  template <typename F>
  void assign(F&& f)
  {
    any_ = ::std::forward<F>(f);

    assign<F>(extract_signature(::std::forward<F>(f)));
  }

  template <typename ...A>
  auto operator()(A&& ...args)
  {
    return invoke(::std::forward<A>(args)...);
  }

  template <typename ...A>
  Any apply(::std::tuple<A...> const& m)
  {
#ifndef NDEBUG
    assert(type_id<::std::tuple<A...> >() == tuple_type_id_);
#endif // NDEBUG

    Any result;

    f_(any_, &m, &result);

    return result;
  }

  template <typename ...A>
  auto invoke(A&& ...args)
  {
    return apply(
      ::std::tuple<arg_type_t<A>...>{::std::forward<A>(args)...}
    );
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "stdanyfunction.hpp"

struct S
{
  void apply()
  {
    ::std::cout << "applied" << ::std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  any_function<> f(
    []()
    {
      ::std::cout << "hello world" << ::std::endl;

      return 10;
    }
  );

  ::std::cout << ::std::experimental::any_cast<int const&>(f()) << ::std::endl;

  S s;

  f = &S::apply;

  f(::std::ref(s));

  return 0;
}
```